# ng-repeat controller and parent update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been reading a lot on angular scopes and inheritance but I can't get my head around this problem. Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="sensorquery-sensor" ng-repeat="sensor in query.sensors" ng-controller="SensorsCtrl">
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="selected.sensor"
            ng-options="sensor.name for sensor in parameters.sensors">
    </select>
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="selected.definition"
            ng-options="definition.value for definition in definitions">
    </select>
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="selected.operation"
            ng-options="operation for operation in operations">
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have an `ng-repeat` based on `query.sensors`. The values stored in this `query.sensors` array should be simple:

```
{
    name: 'sensor1',
    type: 'temperature'
}
```

But I want to use a child controller: `SensorsCtrl` to handle more logic per sensor and hide the complexitiy of sensors. A sensor can look like:

```
{
    name: 'sensor1',
    attributes: [
        'model',
        'brand'
    ],
    definitions: [
        {
            datatype: 'double',
            value: 'temperature'
        },
        {
            datatype: 'integer',
            value: 'pressure'
        },
        {
            datatype: 'string',
            value: 'color'
        }
    ]
}
```

So it's in my `SensorsCtrl` controller where I want to put the selection logic:

```
$scope.$watch('selected.sensor', function(sensor) {
    $scope.definitions = sensor.template.definition; 
});

$scope.$watch('selected.definition', function(definition) {
    if (definition.datatype === 'string') {
        $scope.operations = ['Count'];
    } else {
        $scope.operations = ['Max', 'Min'];
    }

    $scope.selected.operation = _.first($scope.operations);
});
```

How do I keep the link with the parent `query.sensors[$index]` while transforming the sensor as the user selects different sensors and definitions?

Setting up a watcher on `selected` and updating the `query.sensors` array triggers an infinite `$digest` loop.

Comment: please provide a plinkr or jsfiddle so we can help yu more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which was right before my eyes:

```
<div class="sensorquery-sensor" ng-repeat="sensor in query.sensors" ng-controller="SensorsCtrl">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The `sensor` is a reference to the original object of the parent `query.sensors`. An it's created in the scope of the sub-controller.

So in my `SensorsCtrl` controller, I can just watch:

```
$scope.$watch('sensor.definition', function(definition) {
    /* ... */
});
```

So I can put hide some complexity in this controller while maintaining a proper link to the original element.

It does not answer the question of maintaining a less complex object but it's a different question I guess.